# Copy string in C skipping leading chars

Tags: c

I'm looking over some older C code in Xcode and the compiler is warning me:

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &
```

on this line...

```
char *orig_str;
   ...
strncpy(buff, card->orig_str[1], 2);
```

It's trying to copy the next two characters if it finds a comment marker, `'`, at the front of the line.

I assume the issue is that `card->orig_str[1]` is a `char` not a `char *`. `&card->orig_str[1]` solves that. I assume buff is safe even if card->orig_str is `free`d because it's a copy. I'm an utter noob in C and want to make sure that's the right fix?

Comment: Since the compiler is warning you, don’t you think the message would be relevant to include in your question? And, if the type of `card->orig_str[1]` matters, don’t you think its definition would be important to include in your question? Copy and paste the message into the question. And, if the source code is not long, copy and paste it into the question. If the source code is long, make a [mcve].

Comment: I put in both, but they appear to have disappeared. Re-added.

Comment: Seems fairly self-explanatory `"passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'"` That means `card->orig_str[1]` is type `char` not `const char*` as `strncpy` requires.

Comment: The meaning of the warning is not the question.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a correct assessment is that is what you are asking to have confirmed. (of course `memcpy (buf, &card->orig_str[1], 2); buf[2] = 0;` would be cleaner) Depending on what `card` is, you may need `&(card->org_str)[1]` as `[..]` binds tighter than `->` by C operator precedence.

Comment: Is there a reason for memcpy rather than strncpy? The eol should end the copy in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to "How do I write an expression which returns a pointer that is offset from another pointer?" In your case you need a pointer to the second character in a string pointed to by `card->orig_str`.

Well, do it like this:

```
strncpy(buff, card->orig_str + 1, 2);
```

There is no need for the more complicated `&(card->orig_str)[1]` which is hard to read and understand. It will generate the same code anyway.

*Fun fact: `3 + "abcde"` returns a pointer to the 'd' in the string literal. Don't use such code, however.*

`memcpy()` and `strncpy()` behave equally if there are at least `n-1` characters in the source. Please look up their documentation (on Linux `man memcpy`) for details. I would use `strncpy()` because you are dealing with strings, not some "typeless" data.

**In any case** you need to add the EOL character if you plan to use `buff` as a string! If 2 characters are copied `strncpy()` will **not** append it for you. This could be as simple as:

```
buff[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: And this is precisely why I asked -> There is no need for the more complicated &(card->orig_str)[1] <- that makes my eyes water. Thanks for the answer!